# Erro ao validar usuário Java, Spring

Tags: java, jpa, spring, login, autenticação

Estou com um erro ao validar o usuário junto ao banco de dados.
Fiz o debug e os dados(que veem do front end) estão sendo recebidos pela API.
O método que faz a busca no banco de dados está correto, mas o estranho é que vem o usuário e a senha mas o `id_entidade` e o `id_entidade_administrador` vem `null`, logo invalida a autenticação.

Segue o código.

Classe Entidade Administradores

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Entidades_administradores")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Entidadesadministradores.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Entidadesadministradores e"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Entidadesadministradores.findByIdentidadeadministrador", query = "SELECT e FROM Entidadesadministradores e WHERE e.identidadeadministrador = :identidadeadministrador"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Entidadesadministradores.findByUsuarioadministrador", query = "SELECT e FROM Entidadesadministradores e WHERE e.usuarioadministrador = :usuarioadministrador"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Entidadesadministradores.findBySenhaadministrador", query = "SELECT e FROM Entidadesadministradores e WHERE e.senhaadministrador = :senhaadministrador")})
public class Entidadesadministradores implements Serializable {    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "Id_entidade_administrador")
    private Long identidadeadministrador;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "Usuario_administrador")
    private String usuarioadministrador;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    @Column(name = "Senha_administrador")
    private String senhaadministrador;                        

    @JoinColumn(name = "Id_entidade", referencedColumnName = "Id_entidade")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Entidades identidade;

    public Entidadesadministradores() {
    }

    public Entidadesadministradores(Long identidadeadministrador) {
        this.identidadeadministrador = identidadeadministrador;
    }

    public Entidadesadministradores(Long identidadeadministrador, String usuarioadministrador, String senhaadministrador) {
        this.identidadeadministrador = identidadeadministrador;
        this.usuarioadministrador = usuarioadministrador;
        this.senhaadministrador = senhaadministrador;
    }

    public Long getIdentidadeadministrador() {
        return identidadeadministrador;
    }

    public void setIdentidadeadministrador(Long identidadeadministrador) {
        this.identidadeadministrador = identidadeadministrador;
    }

    public String getUsuarioadministrador() {
        return usuarioadministrador;
    }

    public void setUsuarioadministrador(String usuarioadministrador) {
        this.usuarioadministrador = usuarioadministrador;
    }

    public String getSenhaadministrador() {
        return senhaadministrador;
    }

    public void setSenhaadministrador(String senhaadministrador) {
        this.senhaadministrador = senhaadministrador;
    }

    public Entidades getIdentidade() {
        return identidade;
    }

    public void setIdentidade(Entidades identidade) {
        this.identidade = identidade;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (identidadeadministrador != null ? identidadeadministrador.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Entidadesadministradores)) {
            return false;
        }
        Entidadesadministradores other = (Entidadesadministradores) object;
        if ((this.identidadeadministrador == null && other.identidadeadministrador != null) || (this.identidadeadministrador != null && !this.identidadeadministrador.equals(other.identidadeadministrador))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entidadesadministradores[ identidadeadministrador=" + identidadeadministrador + " ]";
    }        
}
```

Classe LoginController

```
 @RestController
    public class LoginController {        
        @Autowired
        private EntidadesAdministradoresService eaService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/autenticar", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public LoginResponse autenticar(@RequestBody Entidadesadministradores entidadesAdministradores) throws ServletException {

            //verifica se foram digitados o login e senha no front end
            if (entidadesAdministradores.getUsuarioadministrador() == null
                    || entidadesAdministradores.getSenhaadministrador() == null) {
                throw new ServletException("Nome ou senha obrigatório");
            }

            // busca no banco de dados
//aqui ocorre o erro entAdministradoresAutenticado fica null nesse ponto            
           Entidadesadministradores entAdministradoresAutenticado = eaService.buscarPorNome(entidadesAdministradores.getUsuarioadministrador());

            if (entAdministradoresAutenticado == null) {
                throw new ServletException("Usuário não encontrado");
            } 

            // compara a senha vinda do banco de dados com a senha vinda da tela
            if (!entAdministradoresAutenticado.getSenhaadministrador()
                    .equals(entidadesAdministradores.getSenhaadministrador())) {
                throw new ServletException(" Senha inválida");
            }

            String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(entAdministradoresAutenticado.getUsuarioadministrador())
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "digi2fred")
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3 * 60 * 1000)).compact();

            return new LoginResponse(token); 
        }       

        private class LoginResponse {
            public String token;

            public LoginResponse(String token) {
                this.token = token;
            }

            public String getToken() {
                return token;
            }        
        }        
    }
```

Classe EntidadeAdministradoresService

```
@Service
public class EntidadesAdministradoresService {    
    @Autowired
    EntidadesAdministradoresRepository eaRepository; 

    public Entidadesadministradores buscarPorNome(String usuarioAdministrador){     
        return eaRepository.buscarPorNome(usuarioAdministrador);
    }       
}
```

Classe EntidadesAdministradoresRepository

```
@Repository
public interface EntidadesAdministradoresRepository extends JpaRepository<Entidadesadministradores,Integer> {
    @Query(value="Select e from Entidadesadministradores e where e.usuarioadministrador=:parametroUsuario")
    public Entidadesadministradores buscarPorNome(@Param("parametroUsuario") String usuarioAdministrador);   
}
```

o erro que ocorre é:

> ```
> Usuário não encontrado
> LoginController.autenticar(LoginController.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez se você mudar o trecho

```
@Repository
public interface EntidadesAdministradoresRepository extends JpaRepository<Entidadesadministradores,Integer> {
    @Query(value="Select e from Entidadesadministradores e where e.usuarioadministrador=:parametroUsuario")
    public Entidadesadministradores buscarPorNome(@Param("parametroUsuario")String usuarioAdministrador);   
}
```

para

```
@Repository
public interface EntidadesAdministradoresRepository extends JpaRepository<Entidadesadministradores,Integer> {
    @Query(value="Select e from Entidadesadministradores e where lower(e.usuarioadministrador) = :parametroUsuario")
    public Entidadesadministradores buscarPorNome(@Param("parametroUsuario")String usuarioAdministrador);   
}
```

a sua busca volte a funcionar.

Uma outra opção é de usar o `LIKE` no lugar do `=` como método de comparação.